# Getting the value inside a pointer pointed by another pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a queue that stores thread structures

```
struct x
{
    int n;
    char *c;
    void *f;

};
```

The function below returns a structure defined as the following:

```
struct s {
    void *data;
};
```

When I call `*new = allocate(&x_ptr)`, how can I access the members of `x`?

I tried the following but it does not work:

`printf("%d\n", new ->data->n)`

I get this error: request for member ‘n’ in something not a structure or union

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` has type of `void *`, you need to cast it to the correct pointer type (assuming it is referencing a valid object of that type).

```
printf("%d\n", node->data->threadid);
```

---->

```
printf("%d\n", ((threaddesc *)(node->data))->threadid);
```